# when element exists without using a setInterval

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have 2 dynamic sub-modals that appear/expand within a parent modal. *(parent modals or pre-expanded modal doesn't need the below update)*.

Within two sub modals, that become expanded from parent modal, I am simply **trying to add/invoke a 'back button' and 'close button' in the `.both_submodals__heading` of those two modals**; I am achieving this with the below solution, but I hate the fact I am using a set interval, this also creates console errors when the `setInterval` is checking for the relevant `.both_submodals__heading` until it's found.

```
  on(footWrap, 'click', function (event) {
    let visible = coordinateWidget.visible;
    coordinateWidget.visible = !visible;

    var checkExists = setInterval(function() {
      const coordWid = document.getElementsByClassName('both_submodals__heading')[0];
      if (typeof(coordWid) != 'undefined' && coordWid != null) {
        const closeBlock = document.getElementById('closeCoord');
        const headerTitleTxt =  document.getElementsByClassName('esri-widget__heading')[0];
        headerTitleTxt.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="closeCoord">X</div>');
        on(closeBlock, 'click', function (event) {
          let visible = coordinateWidget.visible;
          coordinateWidget.visible = !visible;
        });
      }
    }, 100);
  });
```

***Via the comment about mutation observers; I found the below solution to be an alternative... but looks like a ton of code.***

---

```
 (function(win) {
        'use strict';

        var listeners = [], 
        doc = win.document, 
        MutationObserver = win.MutationObserver || win.WebKitMutationObserver,
        observer;

        function ready(selector, fn) {
            // Store the selector and callback to be monitored
            listeners.push({
                selector: selector,
                fn: fn
            });
            if (!observer) {
                // Watch for changes in the document
                observer = new MutationObserver(check);
                observer.observe(doc.documentElement, {
                    childList: true,
                    subtree: true
                });
            }
            // Check if the element is currently in the DOM
            check();
        }

        function check() {
            // Check the DOM for elements matching a stored selector
            for (var i = 0, len = listeners.length, listener, elements; i < len; i++) {
                listener = listeners[i];
                // Query for elements matching the specified selector
                elements = doc.querySelectorAll(listener.selector);
                for (var j = 0, jLen = elements.length, element; j < jLen; j++) {
                    element = elements[j];
                    // Make sure the callback isn't invoked with the 
                    // same element more than once
                    if (!element.ready) {
                        element.ready = true;
                        // Invoke the callback with the element
                        listener.fn.call(element, element);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Expose `ready`
        win.ready = ready;

    })(this);
```

Comment: Mutation observers: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutationobserver

Comment: Can we see your html/css as well please?